# Encrypt data in Android and decrypt in Ruby using AESCrypt

Tags: android, ruby, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I'm trying to encrypt a JSON string in Android and decrypt it in Ruby using AESCrypt.

```
AESCrypt.decrypt(dataToDecrypt, secret)
```

With this Java code I could decrypt second half of the data!

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] digest = md.digest();

SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = null;
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey);
byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(textBytes);

String encryptedDataStr = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Raw data is:

> {"device_id":"863438021956196","imei":"863438021956196"}

And decrypted data in Ruby is:

> \xEE\x99\x95\xC5p\x17\x8A\xFB\xF0\xA5\xC7\x1D7\x98\xBD\xD93438021956196\",\"imei\":\"863438021956196\"}

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue, as @GreyS mentions the default IV's are different, `AFAIK` Java creates a random `IV` if you don't supply one. Also pretty sure `AESCrypt` uses `PKCS7Padding`. In any case, to help to work between `AESCrypt` and Android I recently created [AESCrypt-Android](https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android)

Answer (score 1):

CBC mode requires an IV. By failing to explicitly specify one you are relying on defaults. It looks like the default Java IV is different than the default IV for the Ruby code. Don't use defaults.